# Calculate sinus with seq and for in shell script

Tags: shell

I tried to calculate sinus in a shell-script with `seq` and `for` argument like this:

```
#!bin/bash

for a in $(seq 0 0.1 1)
do
  echo "a= $a"
  mysin=`echo "scale=10 ; s($a)" | bc -l`
done
```

but I got an error:

```
a= 0,1
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=15): Parameter number mismatch
```

The following example works fine without `for` loop and `seq`:

```
a=0.1
mysin=`echo "scale=10 ; s($a)" | bc -l`
```

Comment: `a= 2,0`? What locale are you running in? Does setting it to `C` for the script help things? `bc` appears not to be taking locale into consideration here.

Comment: It runs fine for me, in bash

Comment: I could reproduce the OP's problem by setting `LANG=de_AT.utf-8`.

Comment: do you mean it is an language problem? how do i solve this?

Comment: ohh... ok, is this a problem with point and comma?? i'm from german

Comment: You can put `export LC_ALL=C` before your for loop to force using the default locale, which will use `.` as decimal separator instead of `,`

Comment: i put `LANG=en_us_8859_1` in the script and it worked. thanks

Comment: You are using `bin/bash` after `#!` instead of `/bin/bash`. Add the leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#!bin/bash

for a in $(seq 0 0.1 1)
do
  echo "a= $a"
  mysin=$(echo "scale=10 ; s($a)" | bc -l)
done
```